# MemoryCache Update List in Thread Safe Manner

Tags: c#, .net-core, thread-safety, memorycache, blockingcollection

I'm trying to fully understand the implications of thread safety in maintaining a `BlockingCollection` inside a `MemoryCache`

The scenario: log recent users that request any page from a site.  Use an action filter on the controller to async log their user ID and the time of the request to a memory cache.

MemoryCache is thread safe, and BlockingCollection is thread safe.  But how does a BlockingCollection within a MemoryCache work?  Is this still thread safe?

My method of interest would look like:

```
private void logUser(int userID) {
    BlockingCollection<UserVisitLogItem> bc;
    if (_cache.TryGetValue("key", out bc)) {
        var user = bc.Where(x => x.UserID == userID).SingleOrDefault();
        if (user) {
            user.LatestVisitUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;
        } else {
            bc.Add(new UserVisitLogItem(userID, DateTime.UtcNow));
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `BlockingCollection<T>`? This class is intended for producer-consumer scenarios. If you want a generic thread-safe container that can be searched for a specific item, your best option is probably the [`ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) class.

Comment: Do you use the `MemoryCache` to access globally the `BlockingCollection`?